# Modify and display abbreviated data in the table generated using D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a table generated using D3 and a json file [ma_voteshare.json](https://jsonblob.com/api/2700cb25-fccc-11e6-a0ba-c7b961ce26a7) based on the following tutorial http://bl.ocks.org/jfreels/6734025. The first column of the generated table displays party name and the other columns show the corresponding numbers (see example below). What I need is to display abbreviated version of the party data for example: Bharathiya Janatha Party as (BJP) and so on. How can I modify the specific party column data. I have attached the Json file.

[image]

```
    d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://jsonblob.com/api/2700cb25-fccc-11e6-a0ba-c7b961ce26a7")
    .await(ready)

function ready (error, up) {
    if (error) throw error;

    function tabulate(data, columns, tableName) {
        console.log(columns[0]);
        var table = d3.select(tableName).append('table')
        var thead = table.append('thead')
        var tbody = table.append('tbody');

        // append the header row
        thead.append('tr')
           .selectAll('th')
           .data(columns).enter()
           .append('th')
           .text(function (column) {
                return column;
            });

          // create a row for each object in the data
          var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
              .data(data)
              .enter()
              .append('tr')

          // create a cell in each row for each column
          var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
              .data(function (row) {
                  return columns.map(function (column) {
                      return {column: column, value: row[column]};
                  });
               })
               .enter()
               .append('td')
               .text(function (d) { return d.value; });
                   return table;
                }

              // render the table(s)
    tabulate(up, ['party', 'won', 'leading', 'total'], 'div#jsontable-up');
} // function ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `data` function.

If the column key is party, extract the first character of each word using regex.

```
.data(function (row) {
                  return columns.map(function (column) {
                      if(column =="party"){
                        row[column] = row[column].match(/\b(\w)/g).join(""); 
                      }
                      return {column: column, value: row[column]};
                  });
               })
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NpfJ4sEgEMC1FIfdlXpI?p=preview)